# QLabel setText not displaying text of QLineEdit if label size small

Tags: qt, qt4

I have  a QLabel in which I want to show text from a QLineEdit. The size of line-edit is bigger than the label so I want to show the label ending with a dotted line

```
ui->LE_Serverpath// contains 20 charecters

ui->LB_UsernameInfo  // having size of 10 charecters

ui->LB_UsernameInfo->setText(ui->LE_Serverpath->text());
```

using wordwrap the line is getting cut but I need dotted lines at the end

```
ui->LB_UsernameInfo->setWordWrap(true);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For further information, please see How to Ask, and take the tour :) –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set an *ElideMode* for the label, you need a `QFontMetrics` instance from label font then set text elide mode for the label. to show dots by end of line, set ElidMode to  `Qt::ElideRight`, on the text copied form `QLieEdit`:

```
//QFontMetrics metrics(ui->LB_UsernameInfo->font()); // QLabel already has font metrics

int width = ui->LB_UsernameInfo->width() - 2;
QString text = ui->LB_UsernameInfo->fontMetrics().elidedText(ui->LE_Serverpath->text(), Qt::ElideRight, width);
ui->LB_UsernameInfo->setText(text);
ui->LB_UsernameInfo->setWordWrap(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

use Qt's layout classes, it will take care of the resizing according to text width.